# regular expression to get between text from 2 tags in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have string like

```
<li class="video_description"><strong>Description:</strong> hello world, This is test description.</li>
```

And i want string like, "hello world, This is test description." That string willbe dynamic everytime.

So, how i can use preg_match option here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use regex to parse html in PHP.

I would suggest to use [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) as it is simple and suits your situation

Comment: yeah, this is the option when regex dont work for you.

Answer (score 1):

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, if you want a regex, you can use this:

```
>\s*\K(?:(?!<).)+(?=</li)
```

See the match in the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/4)**.

**Sample PHP Code**

```
$regex = '~>\s*\K(?:(?!<).)+(?=</li)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Explanation**

- `>\s*` matches a closing `>` and optional spaces
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `(?:(?!<).)+` matches any chars that do not start a tag
- The lookahead `(?=</li)` asserts that what follows is `</li`

Comment: If i put like below then.
preg_match("/>\s*\K(?:(?!<).)+(?=<\/li)/", $sub_page, $matchez);

Then it returns me an empty array.

Comment: @UrjitGandhi Hey there, not sure I understand what you want to say with your comment, but posted sample PHP code just in case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
<li.*<\/strong>\s?(.*)<\/li>
```

Usage:

```
$string = '<li class="video_description"><strong>Description:</strong> hello world, This is test description.</li>';
$pattern = '/<li.*<\/strong>\s?(.*)<\/li>/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $string)){
  echo "Macth was found";
}
```